# union rows for each between two dates start date column and end date column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table,

```
Sr no   name    desig     sdate          edate
1       aa       tt      10/03/2017     20/04/2017
2       aa       tt      21/04/2017     22/04/2017
3       aa       pp      23/04/2017     25/06/2017
4       bb       pp      15/03/2017     22/04/2017
5       bb       pp      22/04/2017     28/05/2017
6       bb       hh      29/05/2017     26/07/2017
```

i want to output this

```
Sr no   name    desig   sdate         edate
1       aa       tt   10/03/2017    22/04/2017
2       aa       pp   23/04/2017    25/06/2017
3       bb       pp   15/03/2017    28/05/2017
4       bb       hh   29/05/2017    26/07/2017
```

What's a SQL query for above output

Comment: Please go read [ask], and https://stackoverflow.com/q/38899464/1427878. Also show us what you have tried so far - SO is not a place to just provide copy&paste-ready code for you without you doing any of the work yourself.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Sir, i have been used Mysql database for above table, am new in programing.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Please do a good and simple write-up.

Answer (score 0):

use query like this hope it will help you to find uniq row

```
select SrNo,name,desig,sdate,edate from tbl_name where convert(date,sdate) between convert(date,'3/16/2018') and convert(date,'3/17/2018') group by SrNo,name,desig,sdate,edate
```